# How to aggregate multiple columns from a list of column names one at a time?

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a dataframe

```
x   <-
id1 id2  id3   id4
1   a    12x   1001    
2   a    23x   2001    
3   a    98y   3001    
2   a    98y   1001    
2   b    12x   2001    
1   b    23x   3001    
2   b    12x   1001    
3   b    98y   2001
```

I am trying to write a function which take all the column names as parameter , does aggregating by count for every column and returns different dataframe (4 in this case) which has one column aggregated.

Comment: Try `lapply(x, function(i) data.frame(table(i)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `map` with `dplyr` `count`

```
library(tidyverse)
names(df) %>%
    map(~ df %>%
             count(!! rlang::sym(.x))
      )
```

-output

```
#[[1]]
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#    id1     n
#  <int> <int>
#1     1     2
#2     2     4
#3     3     2

#[[2]]
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  id2       n
#  <chr> <int>
#1 a         4
#2 b         4

#[[3]]
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  id3       n
#  <chr> <int>
#1 12x       3
#2 23x       2
#3 98y       3

#[[4]]
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#    id4     n
#  <int> <int>
#1  1001     3
#2  2001     3
#3  3001     2
```

Answer (score 1):

I have recreated the object `x` using:

```
text = "id1 id2  id3   id4
    1   a    12x   1001    
    2   a    23x   2001    
    3   a    98y   3001    
    2   a    98y   1001    
    2   b    12x   2001    
    1   b    23x   3001    
    2   b    12x   1001    
    3   b    98y   2001"

x <- read.table(text = text, header = TRUE)
```

You can then use `lapply()` to go through your list of ids and apply an anonymous function, which takes an `id` and a dataframe, groups it by the character specified in `id` and summarises (i.e. counts the number of observations) `df` per `id` group.

```
library(dplyr)

lapply(list("id1", "id2", "id3", "id4"), function(id, df) {
  df %>% 
    group_by_at(.vars = id) %>% 
    summarise(n = n())
}, df = x)
```

It returns a list of 4 `tibble`s (which are an extension of `data.frame`s):

```
[[1]]
# A tibble: 3 x 2
    id1     n
  <int> <int>
1     1     2
2     2     4
3     3     2

[[2]]
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  id2       n
  <fct> <int>
1 a         4
2 b         4

[[3]]
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  id3       n
  <fct> <int>
1 12x       3
2 23x       2
3 98y       3

[[4]]
# A tibble: 3 x 2
    id4     n
  <int> <int>
1  1001     3
2  2001     3
3  3001     2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `tidyr`/`dplyr` solution using `count`:

```
library(tidyverse);
lst <- x %>%
    gather(k, v) %>%
    group_by(k, v) %>%
    count() %>%
    split(.$k)
#$id1
## A tibble: 3 x 3
## Groups:   k, v [3]
#  k     v         n
#  <chr> <chr> <int>
#1 id1   1         2
#2 id1   2         4
#3 id1   3         2
#
#$id2
## A tibble: 2 x 3
## Groups:   k, v [2]
#  k     v         n
#  <chr> <chr> <int>
#1 id2   a         4
#2 id2   b         4
#
#$id3
## A tibble: 3 x 3
## Groups:   k, v [3]
#  k     v         n
#  <chr> <chr> <int>
#1 id3   12x       3
#2 id3   23x       2
#3 id3   98y       3
#
#$id4
## A tibble: 3 x 3
## Groups:   k, v [3]
#  k     v         n
#  <chr> <chr> <int>
#1 id4   1001      3
#2 id4   2001      3
#3 id4   3001      2
```

Explanation: Turn `data.frame` from wide to long format, `count` by keys (column names) and values (entries), and split entries into a `list` of `data.frame`s by keys (column names).

Comment: `gather()` is a function that is exported by `tidyr`

Comment: @clemens You're right; I've added the necessary libraries.